# search in /etc/passwd file using perl

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, substring, etcpasswd

I want to know how do I implement following program.
I want to look through `/etc/passwd` file and search for names that occur in more than one person's full name and prints the full names of those people.
So far I am able to print user names and corresponding ids from `/etc/passwd` file. but i don't know how to search occurrences of username more than once in whole file efficiently.
for e.g

1. `@lines` : this array will contain `/etc/passwd` file data
2. then i'm extracting user name from each line of array `@lines`
3. now i want to search for this user name (found in step 2) in remaining list and if username found then print those full names.

I don't know how should I implement step 3.

Any help and guidance would be great...

For e.g
in /etc/passwd file follwing are the full names stored:
1. vijaykumar yadav
2. sureshkumar jain
3. chandan rai
Then 'kumar' is the username which is appearing in the full name of vijaykumar and sureshkumar then print those two names in the output.

Ouput will be 
1. vijaykumar yadav
2. sureshkumar jain

Comment: You cannot solve this until you learn about Perl _hashes_.

Comment: search google for : perl parse passwd

Comment: providing examples and output would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what output you expect nor if my code does what you want, but the following code first looks for usernames that appear in (part of) someone's full name. It then shows what usernames appear in a certain full name. I know it's an ugly code and probably not the most efficient solution, but let me know if this is the output you expected or not.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open PASSWD, "/etc/passwd" or die "$!";

my @usernames;
my @fullnames;

while (<PASSWD>) {
    chomp;
    # First entry is username, 5th entry is full name if exists.
    push @usernames, (split ":", $_)[0];
    my $fullname = (split ":", $_)[4];
    push @fullnames, $fullname if $fullname ne "";
}

my %found_usernames;
foreach my $username (@usernames) {
    foreach my $fullname (@fullnames) {
        if ($fullname =~ m/$username/i) {
            # Push to the array if full name was already found before.
            # Otherwise, create an anonymous array
            if (defined $found_usernames{$fullname}) {
                push $found_usernames{$fullname}, $username
            }
            else {
                $found_usernames{$fullname} = [$username];
            }
        }
    }
}

# Print
foreach my $key (keys %found_usernames) {
    print "Users: ", join(",", @{$found_usernames{$key}}), " appear in fullname $key\n";
}
close PASSWD;
```